# Aws TransferManager stops when i force close my application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, download, amazon-s3

I am downloading objects(Videos) from aws s3 bucket. Once i call :

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3client);
        GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, entity.getName());
            String s="";
            download = transferManager.download(bucket, entity.getName(), f);
```

all the objects are downloading at background by default even if i exit my application or put my app on background.

BUT if u force close (means i long press my home button and close my application from running list)my application all the objects stops downloading

What are the ways to make downloading running at back even if application stops...

---

I tried with service as well:

```
public class MyDownloadingService extends Service {
    public static Download download;
    File f;
    public static  ArrayList<DownloadEntity> downloadList;
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyDownloadingService getService() {
            return MyDownloadingService.this;
        }
    }

    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       // downloadList=new ArrayList<DownloadEntity>();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Service Destroy",300);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service LowMemory", 300);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       // Toast.makeText(this,"task perform in service",300);
        if (intent!=null) {
            String bucket = "", object = "", file = "";
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

                if (intent.getExtras().getString("bucket") != null) {
                    bucket = intent.getExtras().getString("bucket");
                }
                if (intent.getExtras().getString("object") != null) {
                    object = intent.getExtras().getString("object");
                }
                if (intent.getExtras().getString("file") != null) {
                    file = intent.getExtras().getString("file");
                }
                new downloader(bucket, object, file).execute();
            }
        }
         return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
public static void getList(){
    if (downloadList!=null) {
        SoapCostants.downloadList = downloadList;
    }
}
    public class downloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String bucket,object;
        String file;

        public downloader(String bucket,String object,String file) {
            this.object=object;
            this.file=file;
            this.bucket=bucket;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();


        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          File  f=new File(file);
            // Toast.makeText(this,"Service start",300);
            TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(S3Getter.s3client);
            try {

                GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, object);

                String s="";
                download = transferManager.download(bucket, object, f);
                DownloadEntity entity2=new DownloadEntity();
                entity2.setKey(object);
                entity2.setValue(download);
                if (downloadList==null){
                    downloadList=new ArrayList<DownloadEntity>();
                }
                SoapCostants.downloadList.add(entity2);
                downloadList.add(entity2);
                for (int i = 0; i < SoapCostants.downloadedList.size(); i++) {
                    //SoapCostants.downloadedList
                    if (object.equalsIgnoreCase(SoapCostants.downloadedList.get(i).getName())) {
                        SoapCostants.downloadedList.get(i).setIsDownloading("yes");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
}
```

i used start_sticky for services. But if my application was in background for long time it gets closed. or when i force close my application it gets closed.
i checked it by calling getList() of service class above. But it returns null.

Comment: Please explain **exactly** what you mean by "force close" here.

Comment: Force close means ending application from running tasks

Answer (score 1):

The TransferManager is hosted in your application. Once the application is killed, everything it owns will be killed too, TransferManager included. When TransferManager is killed, it invokes shutdown() in finalized() to terminate all transfers running in its thread pool. If you really want it to continue to run, then you'd better try Service which can survive upon application termination. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html for more details.

Comment: i tried to use services for download. i used start_sticky for services. But if my application was in background for long time it gets closed. can u please suggest?